# Airflow doesn't work on localhost

Tags: windows, docker

I have tried to start Apache Airflow UI on my local machine (Windows 11) but have failed so far. Here are the list of works that I have done so far.

**The contents of the 'docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml' file are as follows:**

```
version: '3.7'  
services:
postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
        - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
        - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    logging:
        options:
            max-size: 10m
            max-file: "3"

webserver:
    image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - postgres
    environment:
        - LOAD_EX=n
        - EXECUTOR=Local
    logging:
        options:
            max-size: 10m
            max-file: "3"
    volumes:
        - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
        # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    command: webserver
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 30s
        retries: 3

redis:
    image: redis
```

**Compose Airflow container:**

```
> cd C:\docker-airflow-master  
> docker-compose -f docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml up -d

Container docker-airflow-master-redis-1  Created  
Container docker-airflow-master-postgres-1  Created  
Container docker-airflow-master-webserver-1  Running  
Container docker-airflow-master-redis-1  Starting  
Container docker-airflow-master-postgres-1  Starting  
Container docker-airflow-master-redis-1  Started  
Container docker-airflow-master-postgres-1  Started
```

**Check which containers are up and running:**

```
> docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS                    PORTS                                        NAMES
74ac4cd4fafb   puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9   "/entrypoint.sh webs…"   2 days ago   Up 40 minutes (healthy)   5555/tcp, 8793/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   docker-airflow-master-webserver-1
1acef40c382a   postgres:9.6                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago   Up 3 minutes              5432/tcp                                     docker-airflow-master-postgres-1
e7adfadd1c38   redis                          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 days ago   Up 3
```

minutes              6379/tcp                                     docker-airflow-master-redis-1

**Check network connections:**

```
> netstat
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    [::1]:8080             LAPTOP-0FSNTPS1:63790  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    [::1]:8080             LAPTOP-0FSNTPS1:63791  TIME_WAIT
  TCP    [::1]:8080             LAPTOP-0FSNTPS1:63792  TIME_WAIT
```

**Open browser on address localhost:8080:**

[image]

What could be wrong that it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the [latest official docker compose file](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.4/docker-compose.yaml)? It worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thanks! Although I can't understand why the previous version didn't worked when containers were up and running.